# Using an iMac 27" as an external monitor for a PC

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, displayport

I have a Dell computer running Windows 10 and it have 3x DisplayPort and 1x vga outputs. I want to connect my `iMac Core i5 27-Inch (Late 2013)` as an external monitor to the dell pc. Can I buy a [Mini DisplayPort -> DisplayPort](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YOQYQWY) (Male-Male) and connect the cable between the iMac and the PC and then use Target Mode to start seeing Windows on the iMac?

If that's not possible, is there any way to hook this up? I know of software solutions but I'm trying to do it physically unless I run out of options.

Comment: Buy the cable and try it. It will probably just work. Post the answer afterwards.

Comment: @orkoden If that was feasible I wouldn't have posted this question.

Comment: If you don't want to risk and buy a cable, why don't you ask Apple support if it can be done? Seems like an obvious place to ask about their product.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple KB : Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-al/HT204592) you could use Mini Display Port cables for the 2009 & 2010 models, but later models would appear to require Thunderbolt.

Comment: I think Thunderbolt is necessary if you're connecting two iMacs post-2010 together (both having Thunderbolt and not old Mini Displayport). Thunderbolt is backwards compatible with Mini displayport by the way.

Comment: You'd naturally assume so, but the KB quite clearly mentions DP *or* TB for the older Mac, & yet no mention of it for the newer ones. That really does lead me to believe if it doesn't say it will work, it's not going to. I think the only way to be certain is take a risk on buying a cable. Drop in a new answer if it works, because that would be very useful info for future Googlers.